# PostgreSQL: Is it worth preparing a statement that simply calls a stored procedure, passing its parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql

If we have a prepared statement like:

```
SELECT my_func($1::text, $2::int)
```

Is there is any gain in speed if I prepare a statement with this call and do the call via the prepared statement.

Comment: Not necessarily speed, but using prepared statements also shields you from SQL injection. So from a security point of view, this is absolutely necessary

Comment: @a_horse Good point about security but I will disagree with the _absolutely necessary_ part. If the parameters are passed by a driver they will be already sanitized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) here:

> Prepared statements have the largest performance advantage when a
> single session is being used to execute a large number of similar
> statements. The performance difference will be particularly
> significant if the statements are complex to plan or rewrite, for
> example, if the query involves a join of many tables or requires the
> application of several rules. *If the statement is relatively simple to
> plan and rewrite but relatively expensive to execute, the performance
> advantage of prepared statements will be less noticeable.*

Emphasize is mine. I think it clearly states in which conditions `PREPARE` can have benefits.

Still, all languages currently provide a native way to prepare statements ([like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247373/to-use-prepared-statements-by-php-for-postgres)), so the overall machinery is executed for you behind the scenes.

To make it short:

- if it is a one-timer from the client, execute directly;
- if it comes from the application and assumes user input, use your platform and it's functionality to prepare for security reasons;
- if statement is executed many times within a session, use any means (either `PREPARE` or platform's functionality) to prepare for performance reasons.