# Ask user for a value with trigger/function on inserting row

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I'm trying to accomplish this:

I want create trigger/function in postgres. That before insert some row ask user in some prompt window for certain value. For example i want do this:

`insert into x (a, b, c) values (aa, bb, '');`

Value `c` should be null on default, but on inserting user can fill it. So on inserting a row with empty value `c` `trigger` is called and asks user to fill it.

It is possible? What is the best way to do this?
I was thinging about something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF NEW.C1 IS NULL OR NEW.C1 = '''' THEN
    NEW.C1 := (HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CALL PROMPT WINDOW);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON T
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_function()
```

Comment: postgres triggers have no prompt

Answer (score 1):

As @Vao stated, there's no prompt on PostgreSQL triggers. What about using [custom defined parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) instead?

```
--Sets a run-time configuration parameter 
SELECT set_config('myapp.conf', 'Test', TRUE);

CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  --Gets the parameter  
  NEW.C1 := COALESCE(NULLIF(NEW.C1, ''), current_setting('myapp.conf', FALSE));
  RETURN NEW;
END$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON T
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_function();
```

Comment: So if my goal is not possible. Can i pass value from a `form` as a `php variable`? So i get `NEW.C1 := $xyz` ?

Comment: Take a look on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247427/7925366).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I ll try do it.