# Which is the correct way to use variables and tables name inside a query with PHP + PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

Im getting syntax error with queries in pg with PHP.
Im not clear about how should i write tables name and variables in queries. Actually im using "TABLE_NAME" and '$var_name' inside of queries.
Specifically on this code i got:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 2: "Nombre_Prod" = COALESCE($newNombre_Prod, "Nombre_Pr...
```

For this query:

```
UPDATE public."Products" SET
        "Name_Prod" = COALESCE($newName_Prod, "Name_Prod"),
        "Price_Prod" = COALESCE($newPrecice_Prod, "Price_Prod"),
        "Cant_Prod" = COALESCE($newCant_Prod, "Cant_Prod"),

    WHERE Prod_ID = $id
    AND ($newNamee_Pro IS NOT NULL AND $newName_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Name_Prod OR
        $newPrice_Prod IS NOT NULL AND $newPrice_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Price_Prod OR
        $newCant_Prod IS NOT NULL AND $newCant_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Cant_Prod OR
        )
```

Here's my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$newName_Prod = "'".$_POST['newName_Prod']."'";
$newPrice_Prod = "'".$_POST['newPrice_Prod']."'";
$newCant_Prod = "'".$_POST['newCant_Prod']."'";

$query = 
   'UPDATE public."Products" SET
       "Name_Prod" = COALESCE($newName_Prod, "Name_Prod"),
       "Price_Prod" = COALESCE($newPrecice_Prod, "Price_Prod"),
       "Cant_Prod" = COALESCE($newCant_Prod, "Cant_Prod"),

   WHERE Prod_ID = $id
   AND ($newNamee_Pro IS NOT NULL AND $newName_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Name_Prod OR
       $newPrice_Prod IS NOT NULL AND $newPrice_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Price_Prod OR
       $newCant_Prod IS NOT NULL AND $newCant_Prod IS DISTINCT FROM Cant_Prod OR
       )';

$result = pg_query($conexion,$query);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use prepared statements with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247373/how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-postgres)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @catcon that's not an appropriate solution here. OP should be using prepared statements and parameterised queries. String concatenation is an unsafe way to include external data in a SQL query - it exposes the database to SQL Injection vulnerabilities