# click button and delete specific database row

Tags: javascript, php, database

I use PHP and When i clik "elimina" button i want reload the page and delete a row of a database. I try use javascript for reload the page and get the value of URL for delate specific row of database. My code is:

```
<head>
<script>
function deletefunction(id){
    window.open("specifica_supermercato.php?id="+id);  //reload the page
}
</script>
</head>
<?php
include'db_connection.php';   //connection my db
$conn1 = db_connection();
?>
<?php
$address=$_GET['address']; 
print("<form method=\"GET\">");
print("<input type='submit' name='delete'  value='delete' onclick='return deletefunction('.$address.')'>");
print("</form>") ;
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $query="DELETE FROM supermercato WHERE address='".$_GET["id"]."';";
        $result = pg_query($query);
        if ($result){
            echo "delete ok<br>";
        }else{
            echo "error<br/>";
            echo pg_last_error($conn);
        }
}
?>
```

Why i can't reload the page and get url parameters?

Comment: Because submitting the form will reload the page and prevent your script from executing.

Comment: Also, please consider the following improvements; 1) switching to [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247373/how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-postgres) to avoid SQL injection and 2) using `POST` when deleting a record from the database (`GET` can have undesired effects, since simply visiting that url from history or having it visited by a bot can lead to data being removed from the database).

Comment: when i click the button i use javascript for delete a specific row of database?

Comment: Javascript can't delete, because it runs in the browser. Why don't you simply redirect within PHP right after you perform the deletion? You don't need Javascript to perform this task.

Comment: I have dellete javascript code and i use oly php. I have change something in the code and now  everything works.Thank you so much