# How can I remove white spaces in a psql insert?

Tags: php, psql, trim

I have a text input:

```
<label for="pt"><b style="color:white"> Company name </b></label>
        <input type="text" name="company" maxlength="100" required>
```

And I want to insert into a psql database:

```
$comp= $_POST["company"];
$comptr = trim($comp);
```

When I have inserted it nothing happened. The data in the table remained the same with multiple whitespaces

here is the insert:

```
$queryres = "insert into company (v1, v2, ...) VALUES ('$comptr ','$v2', ...)";  
$resultsel = pg_query($con, $queryres);
```

Example:

I wrote this in the input:

```
  "     TEST     COMP.  "
```

in the table stayed this:

```
"     TEST     COMP.  "
```

and I want to change to this:

```
"TEST COMP."
```

Comment: Did you look at the PHP fuction `trim()`

Comment: You're actually adding a white space in the end of that string `'$comptr '`. You're also wide open to SQL injections here. You should rather use [prepared statements with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247373/how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-postgres) instead of injecting user data directly into the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete multiple whitespaces within a text not with `trim()` but quite well with `preg_replace()`. Make a combination of `trim()` and `preg_replace()`.

```php
$comp = $_POST["company"];
echo trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $comp));

// putput: TEST COMP.
```

**preg_replace()** https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

**trim()** https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

I prefer shorter form for this solution, make a combination of ***ltrim()* and *rtrim***

```
$comp = ltrim(rtrim($_POST["company"]));
var_dump($comp);
// output: TEST COMP.
```

[rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.rtrim.php) - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

[ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ltrim.php) - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.