# How can I use pg_escape_literal in a query with php 8.1 or later and Postgres?

Tags: php, postgresql

After my site was upgraded to PHP 8.1, I started getting the following error on a query when using pg_escape_literal:

Deprecated: pg_escape_literal(): Automatic fetching of PostgreSQL connection is deprecated

The PHP manual shows an example but I can't my code to work:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php

```
// Connect to the database
$dbconn = pg_connect('dbname=foo');
// Read in a text file (containing apostrophes and backslashes)
$data = file_get_contents('letter.txt');
// Escape the text data
$escaped = pg_escape_literal($data);
// Insert it into the database. Note that no quotes around {$escaped}
pg_query("INSERT INTO correspondence (name, data) VALUES ('My letter', {$escaped})");
```

I have something like this:
$dbconn = pg_connect('host='.$hostname.' dbname='.$dbname.' user='.$username.' password='.$greatpassword);

```
$some_sql="select * from ".$MyTable." where the_title=".pg_escape_literal($search_for);
```

I don't even have to run it to get the error.  The error occurs on the pg_escape_literal($search_for) line.  Since I'm connecting to the database first with a dbname, it seems like it should work.  If I change the sql to addslashes, it works fine:

```
$some_sql="select * from ".$MyTable." where the_title='".addslashes($search_for);
```

Addslashes is not recommended though so I really want to get pg_escape_literal working.  I've tried tons of variations based on the php.net example but nothing works.  Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use prepared statements with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247373/how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-postgres)

Comment: *"I've tried tons of variations"* Why not just follow what the manual says and pass the connection as first parameter?

Comment: pg_query_params() is so much easier to use, and because of that also more secure. You have your placeholders and an array with input. Done.